# How to create Instances and set value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two Model classes as shown below

```
public class CheckViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }
}
public class  MyViewModel
{
    public CheckViewModel[] checkBoxes { get; set; }
}
```

How do I create five checkboxes with Id and isSelected value from myViewModel and send Model to View ?
Ideas?

Comment: I think you would not want to have something like checkboxes in your viewmodel. It is something that belongs to your view not to the ViewModel.

Comment: @mmg666, This is exactly what a view model is for - to represent what you want to display and bind a checkbox to the `bool isSelected` property

Comment: Do you want 5 default instances or 5 instances initialized with specific properties set?

Comment: I have tried like this  MyViewModel mv=new MyViewModel();   mv.checkBoxes[1].id = 2;
mv.checkBoxes[2].id = 3;
mv.checkBoxes[3].id = 4; return view(mv) // error: object reference not set to instance of an obect  @Stephen Muecke

Comment: That's because property `checkBoxes` has not been initialized - `mv.checkBoxes = new new checkBoxes[5];` but I suggest you change it to `List<checkBoxes>` or `IEnumerable<checkBoxes>`

Comment: i have tried   mv.checkBoxes=new CheckViewModel[5];   mv.checkBoxes[0].id = 2; mv.checkBoxes[1].id = 2; ..  but same error @Stephen Muecke

Comment: Sorry, it needs to be `mv.checkBoxes = Enumerable.Repeat(new CheckViewModel(), 5).ToArray();` to initialize the collection.

Comment: Thanks. Solved @Stephen Muecke

Comment: Just take note of what I said about making it `List<T>` The only option you now have to render the controls is to create a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `CheckViewModel` (not that that's a bad thing but you lose some flexibility)

Comment: @StephenMuecke once a wise person told me that "The ViewModel is NOT a control’s code behind. Presentation logic should have no idea what its visual representation will be like and should be independent of any specific user interface implementation." but if you say so then so it is.